# get array into new sheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a function that loads certain data from a dynamic table into an array. The function works fine, when I check the local window I get the correct data. Also when I call the data from a sub, everything seems to work fine till I write the array to a new sheet, then I only get the first record repeatedly.
This is my code:

```
Function LoadData() As String()
    Dim rng2 As Range, intJaNein As Integer, rngZelle As Range, X As Integer, cntAnzahl As Integer
    Dim strAusgabe() As String 'R?ckgabe Array
    intJaNein = 1
    X = 0
    Set rng2 = Range("tblMaschinen[DisplayList]")
    cntAnzahl = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, m_intListIndex, rng2, intJaNein)
    ReDim strAusgabe(cntAnzahl)
    For Each rngZelle In rng2.Cells
        If rngZelle.Offset(, -2).value = 0 And _
            rngZelle.value = 1 And _
            X <= cntAnzahl Then
            strAusgabe(X) = rngZelle.Offset(, -1).value
            X = X + 1
        End If
    Next rngZelle

    LoadData = strAusgabe
End Function  

Sub Test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range, arr() As String
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loeschen") Is Nothing Then
            Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            sht.Name = "Loeschen"
        End If
        Set rng = Range("A1:A19")

        arr = cls.LoadData
        rng.value = arr

    End Sub
```

[image]
This is the locals output when getting to the last row of code (rng.value = arr)

[image]
And this is what appears in my worksheet.

Comment: With 1D arrays you need to use `Application.Transpose()` like this: `rng.value = Application.Transpose(arr)`.

Comment: ^^ This is because a 1D-array as yours is horizontal. Therefor your whole range gets filled with the 1st element in the array. If you want it vertically, you'll have to `Transpose` the array, or read elements one-by-one (when the array would exceed the limits of `Transpose`)